# Android app is only running when compiled using older maven repository

Tags: android, gradle, noclassdeffounderror, android-holo-everywhere

I`m working on a project that compiles correctly but crashes on start when I set new maven repository on build.gradle file.

The project is using the lib holoeverywhere, and it crashes with the error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app._HoloFragmentInflater$1

Until last month, everything was working fine, but suddenly the older company repository went offline and we created a new one. Now, if I set the older repository on my build.gradle file the app compiles and runs successfully, but if I remove the older repository, it still compiles but when I try to open it crash.

The main problem with that, is that new people trying to compile the code for the first time, using new or older repo, gets the crash on start.

So, I think this can be caused by some cache made by gradle, but looking at the .gradle folder I couldn't find anything.

Can some one help me with that?

Here is the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "http://<new_repository_url>/artifactory/simple/libs-release-local/"
    }

    // if I remove comment from these lines the project runs correctly
    //maven {
      //url "https://<old_repository_url>/content/groups/AndroidPublicRepository/"
    //}

    maven {
      url "http://holoeverywhere.cf/repo"
    }
 }
}



apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 131
        versionName '1.5'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    android {
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude(group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core')
    all*.exclude(group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-web')
    all*.exclude(group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core')
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.1.0'
    compile 'org.holoeverywhere:library:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:viewpagerindicator:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:5.9'
    compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.14'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-cache:1.4.14'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-spring-android:1.4.14'
    compile 'org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:1.0.2.PATCHED'
    compile('org.springframework.android:spring-android-auth:1.0.1.RELEASE') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.social', module: 'spring-social-core'
    }
    compile project(':addon-preferences-2.1.0')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to remove HoloEverywhere from your app. It was a great library, but it isn't now. It's not very difficult: just change imports, some little adjustments and `minSdkVersion = 15`. Other option: Material Design.

Anyway, if you *can't* remove it or you can't do it right now:

HoloEverywhere had a dependency with a *patched* support-v4. I think the problem is that you don't have this patched version at your maven repository. You can find this code in the branch [`support-library`](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/tree/support-library).

Comment: Thanks for you help, Brais. Unfortunately, I can't remove holoeverywhere for now, so I'm trying this patch option. But, I didn't understand what I should do. I tried to run `./gradlew internalJar` on the branch, but it fails with `Could not create plugin of type 'LibraryPlugin'`. So, what should I do?